# Rotate a certain angle using PID and mpu6050

Tags: arduino, pid

Currently I'm working with a 4 wheel robot and I'm trying to rotate a certain amount of angle. I used PID_V1 library to rotate this. But when I upload and test the code Robot rotate continously.

```
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>
MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);
double Setpoint, Input, Output;
int enA = 6;
int in1 = 4;
int in2 = 5;

int enB = 11;
int in3 = 8;
int in4 = 9;
double Kp = 8, Ki = 4, Kd = 5;
PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);
void setup() {
 pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);


digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
digitalWrite(in4, LOW);


  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu6050.begin();
  mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);
  Setpoint = 15;

  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  }

 void loop() {
   mpu6050.update();

    Serial.print(mpu6050.getAngleZ());
    Input = mpu6050.getAngleZ();
 myPID.Compute();
    if(0<Output and Output<255){
    analogWrite(enA, Output );
    analogWrite(enB, Output);
    Serial.print("\toutput : ");
    Serial.println(Output);

  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  }
 }
```

I used serial monitor to visualize the data and rotate the robot frame slowly and I figured out values of PWM signal is reduced. But when I powered the motors It rotate continously. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started writing this as a comment, but there are quite a few troubleshooting/predictions here about what could be going on, so I'm posting it as an answer that I'll edit if you can provide more information.

Welcome to *Robotics*, Kasun Thushara. Could you please *edit your question* to include a diagram or picture of how your system is wired? I'm trying to guess by convention, but it looks like you're trying to write an analog value to a motor enable bit (enA/enB) and then you're writing outputs to... input pins? in1, in2, etc.

Given you've got two (enable?) `en` bits I'm going to guess there are two motors, but then your four outputs (inputs?) `in` bits might be setting up directions for a motor driver, or aligning power to an H-bridge for a single motor - I can't tell.

What I do see is:

1. You're only turning your motors on if your `Output` is greater than 0 or less than 255, which means you don't have the ability to change direction if (when!!) you overshoot your angle reference (i.e., when your output goes negative).
2. You never turn the motors off! This is probably as much to do with your bug as anything - what do you do if `Output<1`? You should have an `else` case there that disables your outputs.
3. Your serial message is inside your `if` statement; I would put it just below the call to the PID controller so you can see *all* the outputs, not just the ones that fall within your actionable range.

As stated at the top, I would need some wiring diagram or at least some explanation of how your equipment is setup to make better guesses about where your code could be going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have used PID_v1 library and I tuned P I D values. Thank you @Chuck